# Local rings of affine space in etale topology.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, etale-cohomology

This is probably a very straightforward question. What does the etale local rings of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^n$ look like? (In other words the strict henselization of local rings at closed points)

Comment: I believe it is the set of power series in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}[[T]]$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$ with separable minimal polynomial. So for instance, $\sqrt{1 + T}$ is in it iff $q$ is not a power of $2$. There may be a more explicit description.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+T}$ is not in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_2}[[T]]$ it gives a ramified extension. @hunter

Comment: @reuns Agree. I am not sure if there are power series in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}[[T]]$ which are algebraic but inseparable over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}[T]$ but if there are we don't want them.

Comment: @hunter Let $k=\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$, $f(T)\in k[[T]]$ non-algebraic over $k[T]$ and $R=k(T,f(T^p))\cap k[[T]]$. It is a DVR with uniformizer $T$ and residue field $k$. Then $f(T)$ is inseparable over $Frac(R)\cong k(X,Y)$. Why should we remove it from $\overline{Frac(R)}\cap k[[T]]$ when constructing $R^{sh}$ ?

Comment: I think it is about the finite presentation part. So the question is then if this is equivalent, keeping finitely presented and removing inseparable elements.

Comment: @reuns If I understand correctly, $R^{sh}$ should be initial with respect to the property that a polynomial with a simple root mod the maximal ideal also has a simple root in $R^{sh}$.  Since $f(t)$ is not a root of a polynomial which has a simple root mod the maximal ideal, it doesn't need to be included. I might be confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strict henselization of a DVR is (up to isomorphism) the smallest DVR extending the valuation where Hensel lemma holds and with separably closed residue field.

- The strict henselization of $\Bbb{F}_q[T]_{(T)}$ is $\overline{k(T)}\cap k[[T]]$ where $k=\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$:

  If $a(T^p)\in k[[T^p]]$ is algebraic over $k(T)$ then $\sum_{n=0}^N c_n(T)a(T^p)^n=0$. Write $c_n(T)=\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} T^m c_{n,m}(T^p)$ with $c_{n,m}(T^p)\in k(T^p)\subset k((T^p))$ then
  $\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} T^m \sum_{n=0}^N c_{n,m}(T^p)a(T^p)^n=0$ implies that each $\sum_{n=0}^N c_{n,m}(T^p)a(T^p)^n=0$. Whence the minimal polynomial of $a(T^p)$ is in $k(T^p)[Y]$ **from which $\overline{k(T)}\cap k[[T]]$ is separable over $k(T)$**.

  I doubt there is any simple characterization of the elements of $\overline{k(T)}\cap k[[T]]$.
- For $f(T)\in \Bbb{F}_q[T]$ irreducible, $f(T)=(T-\alpha)g(T)\in k[T]$, the strict henselization of $\Bbb{F}_q[T]_{(f(T))}$ is the same as the strict henselization of $\Bbb{F}_q[T]_{(f(T))}[\alpha,g(T)^{-1}]\cong \Bbb{F}_q(\alpha)[T]_{(T)}$ which is again $\overline{k(T)}\cap k[[T]]$.
- For the local ring $\Bbb{F}_q[T]_{\{0\}}=\Bbb{F}_q(T)$ at the generic point, its strict henselization is $\Bbb{F}_q(T)^{sep}$.